# Python dependency issue

Tags: python, python-3.4

I've my scripts setup in the following way -

**a.py** (Newly added script)

```
from b import B
import c  

class A(B):  
def process(self):  
   super().method()  
   c.method1()
   c.method2()
```

**b.py** (Existing script in Prod)

```
import c
class B(Exception):  
def method(self):  
   c.method1()
   c.method2()
```

**c.py** (Existing script in Prod)

```
def method1()... 
def method2()...
```

The dir's that hold b.py & c.py are all in PATH in PROD host.

When I invoke a.py from a scheduler, i get `'module' object has no attribute method()` error. Also method1() & method2() in b.py don't get executed.

a.py is in the same dir as b.py, so i'm assuming nothing need to be updated in PATH.

I searched here in SO and found this could be circular dependency issue, however few of the solutions that were suggested didn't work in my case.

Any suggestions on how i can fix this issue? Also what is the best way to resolve these issues if i were to create more scripts in the same dir as existing ones.

Comment: I do not see any circular dependencies in your code. What is `super().method()` supposed to do?

Comment: super().method() is supposed to call the method in b.py, which it does. I've import c listed in a.py & b.py which makes me believe there's a circular dependency issue.

Comment: If it does, then this cannot be the complete code, are those calls actually inside a class in your actual code?

Comment: Yes, it is inside a class. I didn't list out the complete code as i mentioned in my comment below. Not sure if i'm supposed to give out the whole code here. Maybe i'll edit and give more info.

Comment: No you do not need to give out the whole code, but we would require a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I understand. I just edited my question to hopefully conform to the Minimal, Complete & Verifiable example. If it's still incomplete, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

- what do you expect `super()` to return? It's meant to be called within a method of a class, not directly within a module.
- I'd expect to see a definition of class or function **B** in b.py, since it's what you import in *a.py*.

Comment: Yes, super() is called from within method and there is a class B in b.py. I didn't want to list out my code here, so just gave the core snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my previous response (which was about indenation)

So I've been trying to reproduce your problem. This is what I have:

**a.py**

from b import B 
import c

```
class A(B):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        print('a init')

    def process(self):
        super().method()
        c.method1()
        c.method2()


a = A()
a.process()
```

**b.py**

```
import c

class B(Exception):
    def __init__(self):
        print('b init')

    def method(self):
        print('b start')
        c.method1()
        c.method2() 
        print('b done')
```

**c.py**

```
def method1():
    print(1)

def method2():
    print(2)
```

Invoking `a.py` from the commandline: `python3.4 a.py` my output is:

```
b init
a init
b start
1
2
b done
1
2
```

(which is what you would expect)
tl;dr: could not reproduce.

Comment: I already got few downvotes for this :). However in my actual code, everything is properly indented including class definition etc. While copy pasting i might have missed some indentation causing it look unformatted. Sorry.

Comment: I ran this on both python 2.7 and 3.4....python 2.7 gave me `TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)` whereas python 3.4 ran perfectly fine. How are you invoking a.py?

Comment: By giving the full path for a.py. The dir's that hold these scripts are part of PYTHONSCRIPTS env variable which is included in path.

Comment: How are you calling the `A.process()` method? Creating an instance of `A` (ie. `a = A()` ) and then calling the method on that new instance? (ie `a.process()`)

Comment: As part of a.py's init, I also call b.py's init(). After that i call a.process()

Comment: I've updated my response with a mock up...I still can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks so much for your time and effort. I'll do some refactoring and see if i can get the issue resolved and mark the item as resolved for now.

Answer (score 0):

First off - don't use super().method() to access a parent's method. This isn't necessary. the process method of class A should be:

```
def process(self):
    self.testmethod()
    c.method1()
    c.method2()
```

You haven't posted enough code to actually show the error.

When I redefine `process` as above, and instantiate an object of class A:

```
tester = A()
tester.process()
```

the process method works as expected.